# R package caret using recipe and bak for data preproccesing

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm, lasso-regression

i have a data set from https://rpubs.com/rhuebner/HRCodebook-13 with a lot of character and numeric values which i need to make logistic regression on.
I need to apply the R package caret to prepare the data. my dependend/target variable is the employmentStatus with 4 categories where i need to predict the "Voluntarily Terminated" and make in binary to "yes" or 1. the other three categories need to be "no" or 0.

to prepare the data i did the following but i seems to get error codes when running the code. can somebody help me?

```
   data <- HRDataset_v13 %>% 
  dplyr::select(-Employee_Name, -EmpID, -MarriedID, -MaritalStatusID, -GenderID, -EmpStatusID,
                -DeptID, -FromDiversityJobFairID, -PositionID, -Zip, -ManagerID,
                -LastPerformanceReview_Date, -DaysLateLast30, -DateofTermination) %>% 
  #mutate(DOB = as.Date(DOB, format="%m/%d/%y")) %>% 
  mutate(HispanicLatino = fct_recode(HispanicLatino,
                                     "No" = "no",
                                     "Yes" = "yes"
  ))%>%
  mutate(Position=as.factor(Position))%>%
  mutate(MaritalDesc =as.factor(MaritalDesc ))%>%
  mutate(CitizenDesc=as.factor(CitizenDesc))%>%
  mutate(RaceDesc=as.factor(RaceDesc))%>%
  mutate(TermReason=as.factor(TermReason))%>%
  mutate(EmploymentStatus=as.factor(EmploymentStatus ))%>%
  mutate(Department=as.factor(Department))%>%
  mutate(PerformanceScore=as.factor(PerformanceScore))%>%
  mutate(RecruitmentSource=as.factor(RecruitmentSource))%>%
  mutate(ManagerName =as.factor(ManagerName ))%>%
  mutate(Sex =as.factor(Sex ))%>%
  na.omit(data)
#must be runing alone
  data$EmploymentStatus=revalue(data$EmploymentStatus, c("Active"="No", "Future Start"="No",
                                                            "Leave of Absence"="No", "Terminated for Cause" = "No",
                                                            "Terminated for Cause" = "No", "Voluntarily Terminated"="Yes"))
  data$Sex=revalue(data$Sex, c("F"="0", "M"="1"))
```

i then bake it like this with caret

```
set.seed(123)  # for reproducibility
churn_split <- initial_split(data, prop = .7, strata = "EmploymentStatus")
churn_train <- training(churn_split)
churn_test  <- testing(churn_split)

library(recipes)
blueprint_termd <- recipes::recipe(EmploymentStatus ~ ., data = churn_train) %>% #want to make sure there are no data leakage from the test set into the training set
  step_nzv(all_nominal()) %>% #remove near zero variances
  step_zv(all_nominal()) %>%  #remove zero variances
  step_integer(Position) %>%#rangering - assuming that the distance between the difference the level are the same!!!
  step_center(all_numeric(), -all_outcomes()) %>% #center and scale alle variable - standardize all numeric variables
  step_scale(all_numeric(), -all_outcomes())

prepare <- prep(blueprint_termd, training = churn_train)
baked_train <- bake(prepare, new_data = churn_train)
str(baked_train)

library(glmnet)   # for implementing regularized regression
library(caret) 

tr_control_oneSE <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10,
                                 selectionFunction = "oneSE",
                                 classProbs = TRUE,                 
                                 summaryFunction = prSummary)
set.seed(123)
glm_mod <- train(
  EmploymentStatus~., 
  data = churn_train, 
  method = "glm",
  family = "binomial",
  trControl = tr_control_oneSE,
  metric = "AUC"
)
```

with this error code

```
Error in lognet(x, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, alpha, nobs,  : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 5)
In addition: Warning message:
In lognet(x, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, alpha, nobs,  :

Error in lognet(x, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, alpha, nobs,  : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 5)
```

if i run the model glm model like this i dont get any error

```
set.seed(123)
glm_mod <- train(
  EmploymentStatus~., 
  data = churn_train, 
  method = "glm",
  family = "binomial",
  trControl = tr_control_oneSE,
  metric = "AUC"
)
```

hence the problem is in the blueprint.
thanks in advance